# Partially changing the color of text in a text box

Tags: matlab, colors, textbox, latex, matlab-figure

I am trying to include a small textbox with a table showing results in a plot. In the table I want to change the text color of only single words or symbols.

The table is created using tabular and LaTeX markup. For some reason some of the commands from the [TextBox Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.shape.textbox-properties.html) like `\it` work, while `\color{red}` for example doesn't work. Do you know a way to make it colored?

```
figure
str = '\begin{tabular}{lr} $\it test$ & A \\  $\color{magenta} test$ & A\end{tabular}';  
h = annotation('textbox',[.15 .15 .2 .28],...  
            'Interpreter', 'latex',...
            'FitBoxToText','on',...
            'EdgeColor','black',...
            'BackgroundColor', [1 1 1]);
set(h, 'String', str);
```

Comment: IIRC MATLAB simply doesn't have all TeX commands implemented. Some work, some don't.

Comment: @Adriaan I think it does not contain packages, `\color` is from `xcolor` package

Comment: What is the question here? Why it doesnt work, or how to make it colored?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The question is how to make it colored?

Answer (score 5):

You can cheat and use an undocumented jLabel object, which supports HTML markup.

```
figure
str = '<HTML><FONT color="red">Hello</Font></html>';  
jLabel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JLabel',str);
[hcomponent,hcontainer] = javacomponent(jLabel,[100,100,40,20],gcf);
```

You can make HTML tables as well:

```
str = ['<HTML><FONT color="red">Here is a table</Font>'...
       '<table><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>'...
       '<tr><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr></html>'];  
jLabel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JLabel',str);
[hcomponent,hcontainer] = javacomponent(jLabel,[100,200,150,250],gcf);
```

You can read more about jLabel components in Matlab [here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlab-labels), and about HTML [here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents). Credit goes to Yair Altman's blog.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're running into is that text coloring is only supported when the [`Interpreter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html#budt_bq-1_sep_shared-Interpreter) property is set to `'tex'`, but the [tabular environment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) is only supported when the interpreter is set to `'latex'`. Your best workaround is probably to use [the jLabel option suggested by Zep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100311/52738).

The only way I can see to do it otherwise is to use the `'tex'` interpreter and manage the horizontal element spacing yourself. You can use a [cell array of strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) to create multi-line text:

```
str = {'{\it test}   A', '{\color{magenta} test}   A'};
set(h, 'Interpreter', 'tex', 'String', str);
```

[image]